# TreasuryDirect / Treasury bond question

Tags: united-states, government-bonds

I inherited old paper Treasury bonds and don't know what to do with them.

Questions:

- Before I give TreasuryDirect my SSN, is it a legitimate US bond site?
- Has anyone been able to mass upload the bond numbers so I can calculate how much tax I will owe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are a talking about https://www.treasurydirect.gov/  then yes it is a legitimate site. It is a US government site run by the US department of the treasury.

> Brought to you by...
>
> TreasuryDirect is brought to you by the U.S. Department of the
> Treasury Bureau of the Fiscal Service. The mission of  the Fiscal
> Service is to borrow the money needed to operate the federal
> government and to account for the resulting debt. We do this by
> offering you a variety of savings and investment products.

I entered a long list of bonds a few years ago into the system. I don't think it was very hard to do.

Comment: Thanks.  Did you enter your bond one-at-a-time or upload a spreadsheet or csv?

Comment: It was about 5 years ago, so I don't remember how I did it. It is also possible the interface changed. I probably did have them in a file and then uploaded them.